# Stuck at GTP tunnel Creation

Tags: kernel-modules, tunneling

I'm building an application which communicates with a node called SGSN, using GTPv1 tunneling.

+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

```
     SGSN -----(GTPv1)-----> (my_App)
```

+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

Everything is going well at GTP-C side (Control Plane).

SGSN and my_App are sharing all the needed informations successfully:

- GSN Address/Port for Control Plane
- GSN Address/Port for User Plane
- TEID(peer/local) for CONTROL_PLANE
- TEID(peer/local) for DATA I
- etc...

But at User Plane, when the SGSN actually attempts to set up the related GTP tunnel with me, I have no idea on how to accept this **GTP tunnel**.

I got started with **Linux GTP.ko** but cannot find relevant technical documentations.

IP_GRE module is quite well documented and working very well, but of no help for my small project.

***Can anyone give some clues or tips please, or some steps, about GTP tunnel?***

Thanks a lot,

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Since my goal is to establish and manage a GTP tunnel from user space:

- I suggested GTP.ko
- but I recently found Vector Packet Processing as well, which seems a nice way to go

[VPP](https://fd.io/) is a powerful platform with several amazing features, and it can be driven through low level interface (suitable for C language) .

Best Regards,